# Cannot install app which is built by flutter/xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am building my application by flutter.
It has already published in Appstore, and it was launched normally before updating mac version and ios version to sonoma 14.0, and 17.0.3.
xcode was also updated to 15.0

Error code from xcode is shown below. Can I ask what I should do to resolve this?

```
Installation on this device is prohibited by ManagedConfiguration
Domain: IXRemoteErrorDomain
Code: 9
Failure Reason: Unhandled error domain IXRemoteErrorDomain, code 9
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[IXSRemoteInstaller initWithRemoteInstallOptions:xpcAssetStream:assetSize:error:]";
    SourceFileLine = 140;
}
--
Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone13,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.0.3 (21A360)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "348.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.2.4";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 26745;
    "operation_errorCode" = 9;
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError.3002.IXRemoteErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 8192;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos17.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--
System Information
macOS Version 14.0 (Build 23A344)
Xcode 15.0 (22265) (Build 15A240d)
Timestamp: 2023-10-14T10:22:46+09:00*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says `Installation on this device is prohibited by ManagedConfiguration`. Are you certain that the iPhone is not managed by an MDM? Check iPhone Settings app for General -> VPN & Device Management to determine if any profiles are installed that might be limiting adhoc deployments.

Alternatively, can you build and launch on an iPhone simulator?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and yes, my iPhone installed the profile for adhoc.
Once I deleted the profile, the app was launched regularly. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with my application, struggled with it for hours.  I felt really dumb when I realized I had turned on parental controls the night before, and forgot to turn them off.  Doh!

On the iPad:

```
Settings > Screen Time > Content & Privacy Restrictions
```